# JBoss AS7 domain managed setup

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Is it necessary to have a separate instance to act as a domain master host controller? Can the same JBoss installation also startup slave host controllers with server groups running multiple server instances on different port offsets?

So if there are 2 VMs that need to run 3 server instances in each, can the first VM also be the domain controller? Or is it a good idea to have a separate domain controller running on either one of these 2 VMs or a different one?

Does the domain controller create a single point of failure in controlling the multiple instances? What happens if the domain controller goes down? Does it have to be brought up to start and stop the slave host controllers and their server instances?

Answer (score 1):

You can run several JBoss instances on each host, simply add `server` elements in the `host-master.xml` file.

As for the ports the domain controller (like the host controller, as a domain controller is a host controller with an extra centralization role) only opens the management ports. Only one controller (host or domain) is present per node. One JBoss server is created for each `server` in the `servers` host configuration file (with the possiblity to provide a port offset).

I think giving one thing to run per VM made it easier to manage (VM has been made to do that), but if you are limited resource wise (VMs have overhead), you can use one node to be your domain controller + JBoss instances.

The domain controller isn't (yet?) clusterable, but when it is down the JBoss instances will still run, so you will only lose the central point of configuration. The JBoss instances will in fact fall back to stand-alone mode, and you will still be able to update their configuration, but only by connecting directly to each one of them. When the controller is back, the central point of configuration will be back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If the domain controller goes does how can i deploy to the domain managed server instances if they are still up assuming they run on different vm's. The only way i can get to deploy/undeploy artifacts to the server instances is via the domain controller if i understand correctly. There is no  access to administrative consoles on the server instances in a domain setup right ?

Comment: You will have access to the host controler (I don't know if they have a console giving you access to the different server on the host per say).  Any ways the CLI interface will give you access on server level.  The domain controler will give you central access to all server node.  If you want to only manage each instance separatly, use standalown mode.